# grep capture regex

Tags: regex, grep, capture-group

I am trying to use grep to capture data below:

```
"\\.xy$"
"\\.ab$"
"\\.ef\\.hi$"
```

I have

```
grep  -Eo "((\\\\\.[a-zA-Z]+)){1,2}\\$" file
```

two problems:

1. It can capture things like \\.xy$, but not \\.xy\\.ef$
2. the returned results have literal $ at the end, why?

Comment: Try using the *extended grep* `egrep` with better support for regular expressions.

Comment: @pavium: I just tried with egrep -o, exactly the same results

Comment: Notice that the `$` at the end of the regex is not escaped.

Comment: @pavium: Egrep is the same as `grep -E`, which the OP is using.

Comment: Good point @Johnsyweb, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precede the dollar with a *single* backslash:

```
% grep -Eo '"(\\\\\.[[:alpha:]]+){1,2}\$"' input
"\\.xy$"
"\\.ab$"
"\\.ef\\.hi$"
```

Or put the special characters into square brackets, which I find more readable:

```
% grep -Eo '"([\]{2}[.][[:alpha:]]+)+"' input 
"\\.xy$"
"\\.ab$"
"\\.ef\\.hi$"
```

Comment: almost works, I like the second approach, one problem: the $ still shows up in the results, but it's not part of the capture group, why?

Comment: `-o` means "show only matching part of line", not the capture group `'(...)'`. What do you mean "almost works?"

Comment: @user775187: You can't with grep, but this will work: `grep '[$]"$' input | grep -Eo '"([\]{2}\.[[:alpha:]]+){1,2}'`

Comment: you can eliminate one more backslash in your readability version:  `grep -Eo '"([\]{2}[.][[:alpha:]]+)+[$]"' input`

Answer (score 0):

You've double-escaped the $ - try this:

```
grep  -Eo '"((\\\\\.[a-zA-Z]+)){1,2}\$"' file
```

Comment: with a single \ to escape $ I capture nothing.